# Reference a Google Spreadsheet Row containing specific Text within Google App Script for spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am having trouble finding a function that can reference a row (the number of that row) containing specific text as criteria.

I thought that `VLookUp` would work, but it's not really. Ideally it's something like this:

```
var Row = Find("This Text", in this range, in this column)
```

And the output would be the rows#.

"Find" is a substitute for the ACTUAL function I'm looking for. If you know of a function in app scripts that can accomplish this, please let me know.

To give you an idea of the code I'm making, here is a section (`Vlookup` isn't working).

```
// Process the user's response. 

var Row = Vlookup("Cancelled",A7:B,2,False); 

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
var range = ss.getSheets()[0].getRange("A14:K14"); 
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveRange(range); 
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
var cell = sheet.getRange("B15"); 
var button = Result.getSelectedButton(); 
var text = Result.getResponseText(); 
if (button == Ui.Button.OK) { 
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
    sh.insertRowsAfter(Row-1,1); 
}
cell.setValue(text);
```

Comment: Use [MATCH()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378?hl=en) instead of a script. Regarding the code you included it has several errors.

Comment: That's funny cause its working perfectly. and it has to be embedded in the script.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, maybe something was lost when you pasted the code like the last }. Try using the code format tool to format your code.

Comment: I formatted your script code; please check that it has the meaning you intended. If you want to mimic Vlookup in a script, just use `getValues` and then run through the obtained values, comparing each to the search key. A couple of `for` loops is all it takes.

Answer (score -3):

You can use MATCH to return the row number. For example if you're looking for the word "Help" in Column H, and it's on row 14:

```
=MATCH("Help",H:H,0)
```

will return 14.

Comment: The question is about a script, not a spreadsheet function.

Comment: He mentioned considering using VLOOKUP, so a formula was not off the table necessarily. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: My pleasure. He mentioned vlookup thinking it would work from a script.